# How to preload part of video so there is no buffering?

Tags: video, preload, buffering

Is there a way to preload part of the video (show a loading bar until then), and then start to play it? We don't want any buffering issues on the site.

I tried searching similar topics, didn't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very hard to make sure that there will be no buffering of a video by trying to download enough into the buffer before starting, as network conditions can change quite a bit over the duration of even a moderate length video.

The only way to guarantee it would be to download nearly all the video and even then if the network went extremely slow you might still get buffering at the end.

The usual approach to try to get the high quality experience you are looking for is to use Adaptive Bit Rate steaming.

To use this you create multiple different bit rate versions of your video on the server and break each one up into chunks by time, e.g. 10 second chunks.

The client then requests the video chunk by chunk, with some buffering as normal, and it chooses which bit rate to request the next chunk from depending on the network conditions.

So if the network is good, the user will get a high resolution video experience and if it is bad the resolution will drop. So long as there are a good mix of bit rate versions, this avoids buffering unless the network is very bad.

You can see this technique used by YouTube, Netflix etc - in YouTube if you look at the setting you can play around with it and force it to choose one particular bit rate size and see the effect (if you choose a high one you will probably see the buffering problem you describe unless you are on a very good internet connection).

The approach also allows quick start of video by starting at a lower bandwidth and then stepping up to the higher ones once more video is buffered.

You can also see a nice graphical view of the bit rates steps and the buffer on YouTube by right clicking the video and selecting 'stats for nerds' - it gives a view like this:

[image]

If you really do want to play around with the size of the buffer before you start playback then you will probably need to modify the player itself or create your own player.

In the web player domain, HTML5 players generally now use Media Source Extensions (MSE) which would allow you to control the buffering if you wanted to. MSE is essentially a mechanism to associate a buffer with a HTML5 video src, rather than the usual file or URL. You can then write your own JavaScript you want to fill the buffer as you want. A good intro is here (skip down to the MSE section):

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/#related-technology-1

Comment: you have any idea how these guys [fiveminute.gs](http://www.fiveminutes.gs/) have done it?, they have preloaded a section of the video as loading screen, so there isnt buffering issue

Comment: The loading screen is just an image - the video starts when you get further into the site. You can see this by watching the network tab on browser tools and seeing when the mp4 file is requested. if you have a bad enough connection it will still stall (I was able to see this). They are hosting it on Vimeo and using the Vimeo CDN which will give them very good user experience as a rule.

Comment: i noticed that they are loading a huge file while they show the loading screen [Here](http://www.fiveminutes.gs/scripts/db.js), what is this? looks like mp3 file in base64 format.

Comment: also do you have any idea how they managed to loop a section of the video when on the "retry" screen?

Comment: The file you mention above, db.js is not actually downloaded when I view it (Chrome on MAC) so it may be OS or browser dependent. Looping a section of a video is normally just a matter of asking the player to jump to a particular time.

Comment: what is the best way to compare time in a video? if i wanna pause at 10sec and `video.currentTime` gives me 10.000-10.999, i wanna made sure the pause happens exactly once,right now the pause happens 2-3 times, i am checking this every 100ms, should i be reducing this value?

Comment: I think you probably have two new questions here so I would suggest you ask them separately to get proper answers. On the timing one as a quick initial note, you are pretty much at the mercy of the particular video player you are using when it comes to seeking and moving to a particular time. Its also worth being aware that for a given framerate there may not be a frame that exactly aligns with your time, if you go sub second, so the player has to decide whether the previous or next frame is the best one to display.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, my basic motive was to make a interactive video, i have resolved the time issue, thanks for all the support Mick! you're the best!